# Error on testing my code with qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

This is code for an application.
All the rest functions are being called from `init()`.

How to start with the testing of the code with qunit because if I directly call the function in tests.js file , It says "`ReferenceError: init is not defined` ".

```
var SOUND;
(function ($, undefined) {
// some code here 
// and has variables and functions defined which get called inside this and are all interdependent.


init = function () {
   } 

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How are you running your tests? Typically qUnit is run from an html file that loads: 1. qUnit 2. your application's js file(s) 3. your test js files

Comment: I am running my tests from qunit.html file.
But the problem is I don't know how to write test cases for the existing .js file and need some guidance..

Comment: Your issue is that you are declaring your init function within an [IFFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and it is not accessible to anything outside that function scope. You need to expose it to the global scope somehow.

Comment: How to expose it to the global scope??

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are declaring your `init` function within an [IFFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and it is not accessible to anything outside that function scope. You can solve this by using a very simple "module" pattern that returns the init method from your IFFE and assigns it to a variable.

**JS**

```
// "namespace" for your application.
// Whatever your IFFE returns is assigned to the App variable
// this allows other scripts to use your application code
var App = (function ($, undefined) {

    // some code here 
    // and has variables and functions defined which get called inside this and are all interdependent.

    // example of a function inside your "application" js
    var printTitle = function () {
        var title = document.title;
        console.log(title);
    }

    var init = function () {
        printTitle();
    }

    // expose internal methods by returning them.
    // you should probably be exposing more than your init method
    // so you can unit test your code
    return {
        init: init
    }
})(jQuery);


// since we've returned the init function from within our iffe
// and that function is assigned to the App variable
// we are able to call App.init here
App.init(); // logs title
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyT2t/1/)

I've found the following articles to be helpful in approaching js testing:

- [Writing Testable Frontend Javascript Part 1 – Anti-patterns and their fixes](https://shanetomlinson.com/2013/testing-javascript-frontend-part-1-anti-patterns-and-fixes/)
- [Writing Testable Javascript](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript)
- [Essential JS Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: Could you please explain the code along with the 'namespace'.

Comment: I even tried with your code .
Now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined.
What does this error mean?